# TFS 2015 U1 vNext build Publish Artifact always fails with Unable to associate artifact with resource

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

While trying to execute any vNext build with a Publish Artifact task we end up getting the following error

```
##[error]Unable to associate artifact with resource at location:[location]
```

example log output

```
1 
2016-01-21T19:29:49.9838278Z Executing the powershell script: D:\Agent\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.4\PublishBuildArtifacts.ps1

2 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.1713333Z Preparing artifact content in staging folder D:\Agent\_work\1\a...

3 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.2338323Z Copying all files from D:\Agent\_work\1\s\ASC\ASC-Dev\CSDChangeControlDispatcher to D:\Agent\_work\1\a\CSDChangeControlDispatcher\CSDChangeControlDispatcher

4 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.4838343Z Copying all files from D:\Agent\_work\1\s\ASC\ASC-Dev\PrecompiledWeb\CSDChangeControlDispatcher to D:\Agent\_work\1\a\CSDChangeControlDispatcher\PrecompiledWeb\CSDChangeControlDispatcher

5 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.5150903Z Copying artifact content to D:\BuildDrop\ASC Dev vNext\20160121.7...

6 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.9369728Z Start: AssociateArtifact

7 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.9369728Z ##[error]Unable to associate artifact with resource at location:D:\BuildDrop\ASC Dev vNext\20160121.7.

8 
2016-01-21T19:29:50.9369728Z End: AssociateArtifact
```

Comment: Is this on-premises or on VSTS? If on-premises, are you using a manually configured drop folder on a file share?

Comment: @Wouter-de-Kort
Its on-Premises and it its set to use a drop folder on the same server. TFS app tier and build services are running on the same VM, the folder is ALSO a file share that was used previously in our 2013 xaml build outputs. We do get all the build output in that location even though the task fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is you specify the Path of Publish Artifact as "D:\BuildDrop\ASC Dev vNext\20160121.7".

You should use "\ \ my\share" in Path item instead of a absolute path.

Comment: You are a saint sir. Updated to the share path and everything worked. Should have known.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted, it is the correct answer.

Comment: @PaulSwetz what did you update the share path to? \\my\share\builddrop\....

Comment: Updated answer with the format. computername is obvious sharefolder is whatever the shared folders name is on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if the path has a folder name with brackets in it. For example \\servername\afolder\[foldername].